# Error deploying adf application to IntegratedWebLogicServer (11g) (weblogic.management.DeploymentException)

Tags: weblogic, oracle-adf, jdeveloper, jdeveloper-11g

After activating fast swap for the weblogic server in JDeveloper, I'm not able to deploy my project anymore, and I'm getting a weblogic.management.DeploymentException.
It's an Oracle ADF project and JDeveloper's version is 11g, second release.
When running it on a normal weblogic instance (keeping the default setting "servlet reload") it works.

I tried searching keywords from the log, but I can't seem to find anything.

Here is weblogic's log

```
<4-gen-2023 14.36.31 CET> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149265> <Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID '1672839391501' for task '2'. Error is: 'weblogic.management.DeploymentException: '
weblogic.management.DeploymentException: 
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.throwAppException(BaseDeployment.java:79)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.prepare(BaseDeployment.java:186)
    at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.prepare(EarDeployment.java:58)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.prepare(DeploymentStateChecker.java:154)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.prepare(AppContainerInvoker.java:60)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.bea.wls.redef.ClassRedefinerFactory
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.InitFastSwapLoaderFlow.initLoader(InitFastSwapLoaderFlow.java:70)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.InitFastSwapLoaderFlow.prepare(InitFastSwapLoaderFlow.java:46)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$1.next(BaseDeployment.java:613)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.prepare(BaseDeployment.java:184)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
> 
<4-gen-2023 14.36.31 CET> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149004> <Failures were detected while initiating deploy task for application 'PROJECT'.> 
<4-gen-2023 14.36.31 CET> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149078> <Stack trace for message 149004
weblogic.management.DeploymentException: 
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.throwAppException(BaseDeployment.java:79)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.prepare(BaseDeployment.java:186)
    at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.prepare(EarDeployment.java:58)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.prepare(DeploymentStateChecker.java:154)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.prepare(AppContainerInvoker.java:60)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.bea.wls.redef.ClassRedefinerFactory
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.InitFastSwapLoaderFlow.initLoader(InitFastSwapLoaderFlow.java:70)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.InitFastSwapLoaderFlow.prepare(InitFastSwapLoaderFlow.java:46)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$1.next(BaseDeployment.java:613)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.prepare(BaseDeployment.java:184)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

Where should I watch? Do you have any resources?

Sorry for not being specific, but I'm new to this. Thanks to anybody who may help!

Comment: Which exact JDev version do you use?

Comment: Hi @TimoHahn, it's the Studio Edition Version 11.1.2.1.0, Build JDEVADF_11.1.2.1.0_GENERIC_110907.2314.6081

Comment: OK, this version is very old. I remember that there have been some problems with fast swap in the older 11g version. You can check https://technology.amis.nl/software-development/java/fast-swap-in-weblogic-103-and-jdeveloper-11g-redeploy-after-compile-in-running-application/ if you find some info you not already know. I recommend to look into support  (support.oracle.com payable support contract needed) as there are a couple of pachtes regarding fast swap.

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be fixed by upgrade JDeveloper to newest version

Comment: Thanks for the advice @tung-vo, unfortunately the overall jdev version is imposed by the project, as I'm currently working on a slightly legacy software. I don't know how Oracle updates are rolled out, but I have Build JDEVADF_11.1.2.1.0_GENERIC_110907.2314.6081
Anyway I have to stay with 11.1.2.1.0